# How to get the last key pressed on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm writing a plugin for an application. I cannot derive from NSApplication 
as it is a third party application. I can get the callback in my plugin when any key is pressed. But I will not know what key is pressed. So is there any call in Cocoa to find the last key pressed when I get the callback? I only have NSView object.

Any ideas will help me a lot.

Thanks,

Dheeraj.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Use `[NSApp currentEvent]`.  I know you don't think you have an `NSApplication` instance, but you should try this.  It might work.
2. Do some event monitoring in your plugin (`CGEventTap`, `NSEvent` local monitor, etc) and record whenever you see a keypress event.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Dave DeLong. I have tried CGEventTap but that needs the user to check the Enable access for assistive devices flag in System Preferences.

I will try [NSApp currentEvent] and let you know.